# How to use pd.IntervalIndex.get_loc() / pd.IntervalIndex.get_indexer() with datetime values?

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

Assuming I have the following DataFrames:

```
In [86]: d1
Out[86]:
       Start        End
0 2018-01-03 2018-11-30
1 2018-01-06 2018-11-30

In [87]: d2
Out[87]:
   Document_date
0     2018-10-02
1     2018-10-02
2     2018-06-13
3     2018-06-13
4     2018-03-29
5     2018-04-19
6     2018-06-13
7     2018-03-20
8     2018-06-13
9     2018-01-25
10    2018-05-15
11    2018-04-19
```

I want to create an [IntervalIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.get_loc.html) from the first DF:

```
In [88]: idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(d1['Start'], d1['End'], closed='both')

In [89]: idx
Out[89]:
IntervalIndex([[2018-01-03, 2018-11-30], [2018-01-06, 2018-11-30]]
              closed='both',
              dtype='interval[datetime64[ns]]')
```

and use [`.get_loc()` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.IntervalIndex.get_loc.html):

```
In [92]: idx.get_loc(d2.iat[0,0])
...
skipped
...
KeyError: ('datetime64[ns]', 'both')
```

or:

```
In [93]: idx.get_loc(pd.to_datetime('2018-10-02'))
...
skipped
...
KeyError: ('datetime64[ns]', 'both')
```

or:

```
In [94]: idx.get_loc('2018-10-02')
...
skipped
...
KeyError: ('datetime64[ns]', 'both')
```

**Question:** what do I do wrong?

Example from the online docs which is using integer intervals is working just fine:

```
In [97]: i1, i2 = pd.Interval(0, 1), pd.Interval(1, 2)
    ...: index = pd.IntervalIndex([i1, i2])
    ...: index.get_loc(1.5)
    ...:
    ...:
Out[97]: 1
```

PS I'm using Pandas 0.23.0 (from Anaconda distributive)

Comment: I seem to hit [this bug (current status: `open`)](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/20636) :-(

Comment: The issue has been [closed](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/22988) and is slated for the 0.24.0 release.